# how to configure restart of windows server 2003 using admin account

Tags: windows-server-2003

I want to configure restart of windows server 2003 using admin account. Can anyone suggest how to restart windows server using admin credentials.

Comment: Your question is not clear.
First, what server? 2008r2 or 2003? Second, what do you mean "configure"? script? scheduled task? restart your server from the start menu?

Comment: It is Windows server 2003. I need to schedule a task to restart server with admin credentials.

Comment: There's a built in program named `shutdown.exe` that you can use to accomplish this. Why don't you go Google it and teach yourself how to use it to do what you need. You'll learn something and become a better system administrator. In addition, we don't do `I can has the codez?` here.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I cannot support advising posters to teach themselves because I need rep. >smile<  I am losing to ewwhite and not at all pleased about it.

Comment: @EvanAnderson - Oh. I just looked. He is getting close, isn't he? :)

Comment: I'll sidetrack him with an obscure problem while you answer as many other questions as you can!

Answer (score 4):

I will give you teh codez because I am shameless:

```
schtasks /create /RU DOMAIN\administrator /RP PASSWORD /SC Once /SD 06/28/2014 /ST 03:00 /TN Reboot /tr "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown -r -t 1 -f"
```

Replace the `DOMAIN\Administrator` with the appropriate Administrator account and `PASSWORD` with the appropriate password.

Comment: OH MY GOD WHAT IS THAT DATE FORMAT? Please tell me Windows accepts formats other than Merkin Time.

Comment: @MikeyB I wouldn't be surprised if the date format depended on the current culture in use. In fact, my Australian system says `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: @MikeyB - It is based on your regional settings. I wish it just took ISO-standard time... Grrr...